# A Formula for Congruences

Tags: code-golf, math

The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) can be quite useful in modular arithmetic.

For example, consider the following set of congruence relations:

[image: Set of congruence]

For sets of congruence relations like this, where all the bases (`3, 5, 7` in this example) are [co-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) with each other, there will be one and only one integer `n` between `1` and the product of the bases (`3*5*7 = 105` in this example) inclusive that satisfies the relations.

In this example, the number would be `14`, generated by this formula:

[image: formula]

where `2, 4, and 0` are given from the above example.

`70, 21, 15` are the **coefficients** of the formula and they are dependent on the bases, `3, 5, 7`.

To calculate the coefficients of the formula (`70, 21, 15` in our example) for a set of bases, we use the following procedure.

For each number `a` in a set of bases:

1. Find the product of all of the other bases, denoted as `P`.
2. Find the first multiple of `P` that leaves a remainder of `1` when divided by `a`. This is the coefficient of `a`.

For example, to calculate the coefficient that corresponds to the base `3`, we find the product of all the other bases (i.e. `5*7 = 35`) and then find the first multiple of that product that leaves a remainder of `1` when divided by the base.

In this case, `35` leaves a remainder of `2` when divided by `3`, but `35*2 = 70` leaves a remainder of `1` when divided by `3`, so `70` is the corresponding coefficient for `3`. Similarly, `3*7 = 21` leaves a remainder of `1` when divided by `5` and `3*5 = 15` leaves a remainder of `1` when divided by `7`.

## In a nutshell

For each number `a` in a set of numbers:

1. Find the product of all of the other numbers, denoted as `P`.
2. Find the first multiple of `P` that leaves a remainder of `1` when divided by `a`. This is the coefficient of `a`.

## The challenge

- The challenge is, for a set of two or more bases, to find the set of corresponding coefficients.
- The set of bases are guaranteed to be pairwise co-prime and each base is guaranteed to be larger than 1.
- Your input is a list of integers as input `[3,4,5]` or space-separated string `"3 4 5"` or however your inputs work.
- Your output should either be a list of integers or space-separated string that denotes the set of coefficients.

## Test cases

```
input             output
[3,5,7]           [70,21,15]
[2,3,5]           [15,10,6]
[3,4,5]           [40,45,36]
[3,4]             [4,9]
[2,3,5,7]         [105,70,126,120]
[40,27,11]        [9801,7480,6480]
[100,27,31]       [61101,49600,56700]
[16,27,25,49,11]  [363825,2371600,2794176,5583600,529200]
```

Many thanks to Leaky Nun for his help in writing this challenge. As always, if the problem is unclear, please let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

Comment: Will there always be 3 numbers in the input?

Comment: @xnor Nope. Test cases edited.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>61</s> <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```
f x=[[p|p<-[0,product x`div`n..],p`mod`n==1]!!0|n<-x]
```

Defines a function `f` that takes input and gives output as a list of integers.

```
f x=[                                          |n<-x]  (1)
              product x                                (2)
                       `div`n                          (3)
```

First we loop over all integers in the input (1). Then we take the product of all of the integers (2) and divide by n to get just the product of the non-`n` integers, which is `P` (3).

```
           [0,               ..]                       (4)
     [p|p<-                     ,p`mod`n==1]           (5)
                                            !!0        (6)
```

Then we use the result (`P`) as the step value for a range starting at zero (4). We take the result, `[0, P, 2P, 3P, ...]`, and filter it on values for which the result of a mod-n operation is one (5). Finally, we take the first element, which works thanks to lazy evaluation (6).

Thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for 2 bytes!

Comment: Welcome to haskell! I think your `quot` can be a `div`, and `head` can be `!!0`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
P:*ÆṪ%P
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UDoqw4bhuaolUA&input=&args=WzE2LDI3LDI1LDQ5LDExXQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UDoqw4bhuaolUArDh-KCrEc&input=&args=WzMsIDUsIDddLCBbMiwgMywgNV0sIFszLCA0LCA1XSwgWzMsIDRdLCBbMiwgMywgNSwgN10sIFs0MCwgMjcsIDExXSwgWzEwMCwgMjcsIDMxXSwgWzE2LDI3LDI1LDQ5LDExXQ).

#### Background

Let **P** and **a** be strictly positive, *coprime* integers.

The two-step process in the question – finding a multiple of **P** that leaves a remainder of **1** when divided by **a** – can be described by the following congruence equation.

[image: linear congruence equation]

By the [Euler-Fermat theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), we have

[image: Euler-Fermat theorem]

where **φ** denotes [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). From this result, we deduce the following.

[image: formula for linear congruence equation]

Finally, since the challenge requires us to compute **Px**, we observe that

[image: formula for final result]

where **Pa** can be computed as the product of all moduli.

#### How it works

```
P:*ÆṪ%P  Main link. Argument: A (list of moduli)

P        Yield the product of all moduli.
 :       Divide the product by each modulus in A.
   ÆṪ    Apply Euler's totient function to each modulus.
  *      Raise each quotient to the totient of its denominator.
     %P  Compute the remainder of the powers and the product of all moduli.
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 13 bytes

```
*/|5&p:^~*/%]
```

Based on @Dennis' amazing [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88974/6710).

### Usage

Some test cases will need the input as extended integers which have a suffix `x`.

```
   f =: */|5&p:^~*/%]
   f 3 5 7
70 21 15
   f 40x 27 11
9801 7480 6480
   f 16x 27 25 49 11
363825 2371600 2794176 5583600 529200
```

### Explanation

```
*/|5&p:^~*/%]  Input: list B
         */    Reduce B using multiplication to get the product of the values
            ]  Identity function, get B
           %   Divide the product by each value in B, call the result M
   5&p:        Apply the totient function to each value in B, call the result P
       ^~      Raise each value in M to the power of its corresponding value in P
*/             The product of the values in B
  |            Compute each power modulo the product and return
```

[Try it here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
PowerMod[a=LCM@@#/#,-1,#]a&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
mhfq1%Td*R/*FQ
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mhfq1%25Td%2aR%2F%2aFQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C5%2C7%5D%0A%5B2%2C3%2C5%5D%0A%5B3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B40%2C27%2C11%5D%0A%5B100%2C27%2C31%5D&debug=0)

Naive implementation of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>87</s> 84 bytes

A simple implementation of the algorithm. Golfing suggestions welcome.

```python
a=input();p=1
for i in a:p*=i
print[p/i*j for i in a for j in range(i)if p/i*j%i==1]
```

Comment: A full program would save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
P:×"Ḷð%"’¬æ.ḷ
```

Saved a byte thanks to @[Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)!

Uses the process described in the challenge spec. The input is a list of bases and the output is a list of coefficients.

[Try it online](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UDrDlyLhuLbDsCUi4oCZwqzDpi7huLc&input=&args=WzMsIDUsIDdd) or [Verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UDrDlyLhuLbDsCUi4oCZwqzDpi7huLcKw4figqxH&input=&args=W1szLCA1LCA3XSwgWzIsIDMsIDVdLCBbMywgNCwgNV0sIFszLCA0XSwgWzIsIDMsIDUsIDddLCBbNDAsIDI3LCAxMV0sIFsxMDAsIDI3LCAzMV0sIFsxNiwgMjcsIDI1LCA0OSwgMTFdXQ).

### Explanation

```
P:×"Ḷð%"’¬æ.ḷ  Input: a list B
P              Get the product of the list
 :             Divide it by each value in the B, call it M
    Ḷ          Get a range from 0 to k for k in B
  ×"           Vectorized multiply, find the multiples of each M
     ð         Start a new dyadic chain. Input: multiples of M and B
      %"       Vectorized modulo, find the remainders of each multiple by B
        ’      Decrement every value
               If the remainder was 1, decrementing would make it 0
         ¬     Logical NOT, zeros become one and everything else becomes 0
            ḷ  Get the multiples of M
          æ.   Find the dot product between the modified remainders and the multiples
               Return
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

```
a.map(e=>[...Array(e).keys()].find(i=>p*i/e%e==1)*p/e,p=a.reduce((i,j)=>i*j))
```

I tried the extended Euclidean algorithm but it takes 98 bytes:

```
a=>a.map(e=>(r(e,p/e)+e)%e*p/e,p=a.reduce((i,j)=>i*j),r=(a,b,o=0,l=1)=>b?r(b,a%b,t,o-l*(a/b|0)):o)
```

If the values are all prime, ES7 can do it in 56 bytes:

```
a=>a.map(e=>(p/e%e)**(e-2)%e*p/e,p=a.reduce((i,j)=>i*j))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python + SymPy, 71 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
lambda x:[(prod(x)/n)**totient(n)%prod(x)for n in x]
```

This uses the algorithm from [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88974/12012). I/O is in form of lists of SymPy numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 64 bytes

```
n->n.map(i->(|>i).map(j->(k->k%i>1?0:k)(n.reduce((*))/i*j)).sum)
```

Comment: I should add a `.product` which does `.reduce((*))` for arrays...

Answer (score 0):

### [GAP](http://gap-system.org), 51 bytes

GAP has a function that can compute the motivating example with `ChineseRem([2,5,7],[2,4,0])`, but that still doesn't make it that easy to get the coefficients. We can get the n-th coefficient by using the list with a one in the n-th position and zeroes at the other positions as second argument. So we need to create these lists and apply the function to all of them:

```
l->List(Basis(Integers^Size(l)),b->ChineseRem(l,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 148 bytes

```
@set p=%*
@set/ap=%p: =*%
@for %%e in (%*)do @for /l %%i in (1,1,%%e)do @call:l %%e %%i
@exit/b
:l
@set/an=p/%1*%2,r=n%%%1
@if %r%==1 echo %n%
```

Answer (score 0):

## Actually, 14 bytes

This uses the algorithm in [Dennis's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88974/47581). Another answer based on my Python answer is forthcoming. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O8-AOynimYBcO-KZguKWkkDimYDigb_imYAl&input=WzEwMCwyNywzMV0)

```
;π;)♀\;♂▒@♀ⁿ♀%
```

**How it works**

```
                 Implicit input a.
;                Duplicate a.
 π;)             Take product() of a, duplicate and rotate to bottom.
    ♀\           Integer divide the product by each element of a. Call this list b.
      ;♂▒        Take that list, duplicate, and get the totient of each element.
         @♀ⁿ     Swap and take pow(<item in b>, <corresponding totient>)
            ♀%   Modulo each item by the remaining duplicate product on the stack.
                 Implicit return.
```

Another answer based on my Python answer at 22 bytes. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O8-A4pWWYOKVneKVm-KVnFzilZtyKiLilZtAJTE9IsKj4paRYE0&input=WzEwMCwyNywzMV0)

```
;π╖`╝╛╜\╛r*"╛@%1="£░`M
```

**How it works**

```
            Implicit input a.
;π╖         Duplicate, take product of a, and save to register 0.
`...`M      Map over a.
  ╝           Save the item, b, in register 1.
  ╛╜\         product(a) // b. Call it P.
  ╛r          Take the range [0...b].
  *           Multiply even item in the range by P. Call this list x.
  "..."£░     Turn a string into a function f.
              Push values of [b] where f returns a truthy value.
    ╛@%         Push b, swap, and push <item in x> % b.
    1=          Does <item> % b == 1?
            Implicit return.
```